# Is TextChanged is direct event in Routed Events category

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

I know 'Onclick' is one of the Direct routed events,

And direct routed events are the event which handled by the source itself, but still not clear what all the direct routed events are, all the example given on internet have only used 'OnClick' for direct Routed Events.

Can somebody provide the list of all the direct Routed Events?

Answer (score 2):

> I know `OnClick` is one of the Direct routed events

If you're referring to `ButtonBase.OnClick`, then it's actually **not** a direct event; it's a bubbling event.

> Is `TextChanged` a direct event in Routed Events category?

If you're referring to `TextBox.TextChanged`, then no; it's also a bubbling event.

> Can somebody provide the list of all the direct Routed Events?

Done easily enough from the C# Interactive window:

```cs
> #r "WindowsBase"
> #r "PresentationCore"
> #r "PresentationFramework"
> using System.Windows;
> using System.Linq;
> using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
> var types = from t in typeof(FrameworkElement).Assembly.GetTypes()
.             where typeof(FrameworkElement).IsAssignableFrom(t)
.             select t;
> foreach (var t in types) RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(t.TypeHandle);
> var events = from e in EventManager.GetRoutedEvents()
.              where e.RoutingStrategy == RoutingStrategy.Direct
.              select $"{e.OwnerType.Name}.{e.Name}";
> foreach (var e in events) Console.WriteLine(e);
```

Results:

```
FrameworkElement.SizeChanged  
FrameworkElement.Loaded  
FrameworkElement.Unloaded  
ToolTipService.ToolTipOpening  
ToolTipService.ToolTipClosing  
UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown  
UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDown  
UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp  
UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUp  
UIElement.PreviewMouseRightButtonDown  
UIElement.MouseRightButtonDown  
UIElement.PreviewMouseRightButtonUp  
UIElement.MouseRightButtonUp  
Mouse.MouseEnter  
Mouse.MouseLeave  
Stylus.StylusEnter  
Stylus.StylusLeave  
Touch.TouchEnter  
Touch.TouchLeave  
Control.PreviewMouseDoubleClick  
Control.MouseDoubleClick  
Calendar.SelectedDatesChanged  
DatePicker.SelectedDateChanged  
VirtualizingStackPanel.CleanUpVirtualizedItemEvent
```

Note that the code above will only show you *routed events*.  It won't show you plain old CLR events.

---

#### Follow-Ups

> In your result, PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown is a direct event but as far as I know its tunneling event and similarly MouseLeftButtonDown is bubbling event, please clarify.

It's a direct event.  Check the source code for yourself:

```
/// <summary>
///     Declaration of the routed event reporting the left mouse button was pressed
/// </summary>
public static readonly RoutedEvent PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent = 
    EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown", 
                                     RoutingStrategy.Direct,
                                     typeof(MouseButtonEventHandler),
                                     _typeofThis);
```

Your confusion probably stems from the fact that it *behaves* like a tunneling event.  The button-specific mouse events are a kind of 'sub-event'; they are raised when some *other* event arrives at a given UI element.  For example, `LeftMouseButtonDown` is fired when `MouseButtonDown` arrives with a `ChangedButton` of `Left`.  The same goes for the `Preview` events.

See for yourself:

```cs
private static void OnPreviewMouseDownThunk(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if(!e.Handled)
    {
        UIElement uie = sender as UIElement;

        if (uie != null)
        {
            uie.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
        }
        else
        {
            ContentElement ce = sender as ContentElement;

            if (ce != null)
            {
                ce.OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
            }
            else
            {
                ((UIElement3D)sender).OnPreviewMouseDown(e);
            }
        }
    }

    // Always raise this "sub-event", but we pass along the handledness.
    UIElement.CrackMouseButtonEventAndReRaiseEvent((DependencyObject)sender, e);
}

private static void CrackMouseButtonEventAndReRaiseEvent(DependencyObject sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    RoutedEvent newEvent = CrackMouseButtonEvent(e);

    if (newEvent != null)
    {
        ReRaiseEventAs(sender, e, newEvent);
    }
}

private static RoutedEvent CrackMouseButtonEvent(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    RoutedEvent newEvent = null;

    switch(e.ChangedButton)
    {
        case MouseButton.Left:
            if(e.RoutedEvent == Mouse.PreviewMouseDownEvent)
                newEvent = UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent;
            else if(e.RoutedEvent == Mouse.MouseDownEvent)
                newEvent = UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent;
            else if(e.RoutedEvent == Mouse.PreviewMouseUpEvent)
                newEvent = UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUpEvent;
            else
                newEvent = UIElement.MouseLeftButtonUpEvent;
            break;
        case MouseButton.Right:
            if(e.RoutedEvent == Mouse.PreviewMouseDownEvent)
                newEvent = UIElement.PreviewMouseRightButtonDownEvent;
            else if(e.RoutedEvent == Mouse.MouseDownEvent)
                newEvent = UIElement.MouseRightButtonDownEvent;
            else if(e.RoutedEvent == Mouse.PreviewMouseUpEvent)
                newEvent = UIElement.PreviewMouseRightButtonUpEvent;
            else
                newEvent = UIElement.MouseRightButtonUpEvent;
            break;
        default:
            // No wrappers exposed for the other buttons.
            break;
    }
    return ( newEvent );
}
```

Thus, while the button-specific events are direct events, they piggy-back on bubbling and tunneling events, so they *appear* to follow those routing strategies.

For all intents and purposes, you can *treat* them like bubbling and tunneling events, despite how they are registered.

Comment: In your result, PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown is a direct event but as far as I know its tunneling event and similarly MouseLeftButtonDown is bubbling event, please clarify.

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer.